# Batch consuming of JMS messages

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

The `MessageListener` interface only defines a method `onMessage` that receives a single `Message` as argument. I'm looking for a way to get multiple `Message`s from a queue so that I can process the batch and then acknowledge all the `Message`s in the batch.

Is there such feature in JMS world? If no, is it supported by ActiveMQ as an extension?

Thanks, Mickael

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239204/effective-jms-processing

Comment: If you are intrested in overall performance, this might be interesting as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470691/jms-performance

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in [JMS 1.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7195-jms-1.1-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) section *4.5.1 Synchronous Delivery*:

> A client can request the next message from a MessageConsumer using one
>   of its receive methods. There are several variations of receive that
>   allow a client to poll or wait for the next message.

There is even a code example in Section *9.2.2 Receiving a Message Synchronously*:

```
TextMessage stockMessage;
stockMessage = (TextMessage)receiver.receive();
```

Note that you should also have a look into acknowledgement when using polling and batch processing - see section *4.4.11 Message Acknowledgment* for further information on this. Especially interesting could be the following:

> CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE - With this option, a client acknowledges a message
>   by calling the message’s acknowledge method. Acknowledging a consumed
>   message automatically acknowledges the receipt of all messages that
>   have been delivered by its session.

Comment: The question is now how to do batch JMS consuming asynchronously :) And I found the following JIRA https://java.net/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JMS_SPEC-36. Looks like it is not expected until version 2.1. Do you know if this is possible with ActiveMQ as an extension?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache The topic discussed there is just a convenience feature. There is not much difference when using an own thread instead of using a thread provided by the jms client to process the batch via polling as *a Session uses a single thread to run all its MessageListeners* (Section 4.4.14 Serial Execution of Client Code).

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is part of the regular JMS API. Instead of doing your consumption in a `MessageListener` do it in a loop using `MessageConsumer.receive()`. For it to be transactionally batched, you need to use the `SESSION_TRANSACTED` acknowledgement mode, and call `Session.commit()` when you want to send the batch acknowledgement.

Take a look at the source code for the [sjms-batch](https://camel.apache.org/sjms-batch.html) component in Apache Camel to see how this is done.

Comment: Please see my comment to SpaceTrucker answer.